# Redirect to domain from subdomain (AWS, Route53)

Tags: amazon-web-services, subdomain, amazon-route53

I have a hosted zone for my **www.example.com** domain (Route53), and I have a **subdomain.example.com** subdomain. I've bought another domain **www.domain.com** and I want my **subdomain.example.com** to point to **www.domain.com**. Is there any way to do that without adding another hosted zone for **www.domain.com**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just go to hosted zone www.example.com ; create a CNAME record for subdomain.example.com and put value as www.domain.com

Comment: What name servers should I point in domain center, same as www.example.com or should I leave registrar default NS?

Comment: If I understood u already have hosted zone example.com on Route53 ( i.e. u specified aws nameservers in ur domain service providers ) while www.example.com is still having default NS.. This is just fine.. Nothing extra needs to be done.

Comment: should I add virtual host on my server? because it's still not working.

Comment: using dns entries u just take care of IP addresses.. So now ping on subdomain.example.com and www.domain.com should take you to same server.. Even try doing ssh on both these domains and it should lead to same server..

Answer (score 3):

From my understanding, you currently have an AWS Route 53 hosted zone named 'www.example.com' and a subdomain under this hosted zone with the name of 'subdomain.example.com.' You have recently purchased another domain (www.domain.com) and want to have your subdomain (subdomain.example.com) point to 'www.domain.com.'

Depending on where you purchased the 'www.domain.com' will result in two different solutions.

Solution #1: You purchased 'www.domain.com' from AWS

1. Make sure you have a hosted zone created for this domain [1].
2. Create an "A Record" using the "Create Resource Record Set" button when inside the 'www.domain.com' hosted zone. You can leave this as 'www.domain.com' as the name, and for the alias/value of this A Record, you will point it to the EC2 Instance that is running your site [2]. (If you are pointing your web site traffic to go through and ELB, S3 bucket, etc.. then you can follow this link below [3])
3. Go to the hosted zone for 'www.example.com' and make sure your subdomain (subdomain.example.com) is using a CNAME record. If not, then you will need to delete this resource record and add a new one with the same name and for the value, you will put in 'www.domain.com'.
4. Once this is complete, then you can verify that this is working as intended by placing 'subdomain.example.com' in your browser and seeing if it redirects to 'www.domain.com'. You can also run a dig [1] curl command to see if you are able to pull up the site and resource record information.

Solution #2: You purchased 'www.domain.com' from somewhere else that was not AWS

1. Make sure you have your hosted zone has the subdomains you want to use (such as 'www.example.com) to use the CNAME of 'www.domain.com'.
2. Update your NS record for the parent domain 'www.domain.com' to use the NS records that are for your Route 53 hosted zone 'www.example.com' (there will be 4 of them) [5].

If you run into any issues with what was stated here, then please let us know where you bought www.domain.com and what you are currently seeing as the issue with any results you can provide.

[1] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingHostedZone.html

[2] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-ec2-instance.html

[3] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-aws-resources.html

[4] https://www.digwebinterface.com

[5] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewSubdomain.html#UpdateDNSParentDomain

Comment: I need to do solution 2 but it is not clear. I have added CNAME to point to `www.domain.com` hosted elsewhere. it works but the url name does not change. url shows `subdomain.example.com` but displays `www.domain.com`

Answer (score 1):

While @Deepak's answer works, you'll probably need to create a hosted zone for `www.domain.com`

One solution is to go to the DNS settings of your domain from your domain provider (if it's available), and add A Name records for it.